# Why does a function in a class does not return anything?

Tags: python, class, binary-search

For exercising reasons, I am trying to implement a **class** `SSM` which stands for **Static Sorted Map** in python in order to implement the methods

`min_value(self)` : find the minimum value

`max_value(self)` : find the maximum value

`search(self, key)`: to find an element in the list

The list is assumed to be sorted.

Here is the code for the class:

```
class SSM:
    def __init__(self, A):
        self.sorted_list = A[:] #the list, assume A is sorted

    def min_value(self):
        return self.sorted_list[0]
    
    def max_value(self):
        return self.sorted_list[-1]
    
    def search(self, K): 

        def __Bin_Search(s, e, K): # local function # implementation pseudocode
            if s == e:
                if self.sorted_list[s] == K:
                    return True, s # return True and position
                else:
                    return False

                x =  math.ceil((s+e)/2)
                if self.sorted_map[x] == K:
                    return  True, x # return True and position

                if self.sorted_list[x] > K:
                    return __Bin_Search(s, x-1, K) # go recursive
                else:
                    return __Bin_Search(x+1, e, K) # go recursive
                
        return __Bin_Search(0, len(self.sorted_list), K) # call __Bin_Search
```

As you can see from the code, for the method `search (self, K)` I have an inner function `__Bin_Search(s, e, K)` which goes recursive on the left or right of the list in order to find the element (it is based on the Binary Search Algorithm).
And so, I expect that the methods `search (self, K)` returns the result given by `__Bin_Search` since it is called in the last line.

My problem is that by using `search(self, K)` nothing is returned.

```
A = [45, 33, 36, 30, 27, 40, 16, 27]
A.sort()
ssm = SSM(A)

ssm.search(33)
```

Where is the error in the code? How can I fix that?

Comment: In your first if clause, what happens if `s =! e`?

Comment: @jfaccioni it returns False

Comment: It returns `None`, which is the default return value when you don't specify it with a `return` statement. Since the `if s == e:` has no matching `else` clause, your function returns `None`.

Comment: your inner functions runs `if ...; return ... else: return ...` - so it always runs `return` and all code after this `if/else` will be never executed. Maybe you have wrong indentations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list always has a length greater than `0` so s will never equal e and therefore never reach a return statement. You need to add a conditional statement in `__Bin_Search` where `s != e`.